# Windows Subsystem for Linux home versus Windows Environment home

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to get it to connect to my github, but keep getting an error.
I think it thinks I'm a different user :( ... (don't ask why i have two similarly named users, i don't even know anymore...)

```
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
```

because there's definitely a `C:\Users\solar\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`

I can't figure out how to switch or how to get to that file :(

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  Your question doesn't provide enough information to work out what the problem is.  How are you attempting to connect to github -- what is the exact command that you run when this message appears?  Is there any other output?  Does the same identity file work from other machines?

Comment: @JigglyNaga, hi! Sorry, i was using `ssh -vT git@github.com` I don't have other machines to try it on unfortunately

Comment: @JigglyNaga I added more stuff. Let me know if you have any suggestions please.

Comment: The error output you posted is because your script has CRLF line endings. It's not related to the title question.

Comment: @Michael I don't know what that means. Could you please elaborate? And I think someone changed the title for me.

Comment: I'm saying the `: Permission deniedgitfiti.sh: cannot create /dev/null` and surroundings is *another* (perfectly valid) question and better separated out from the one about getting your private key copied into the WSL environment, which is what the start & end of the question is about. The original question seems to have been answered, you just need to `chmod -R go-rwx ~/.ssh` afterwards to fix the permissions. You're likely still to have your other problem at that point and you can [ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a second question for it, but SSH should find your keyfile.

Comment: @MichaelHomer ok, i started a new question. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows "home" directory (e. g. `C:\Users\YourName\`) is not your WSL home directory (e. g. `/home/yourname`).  Copy your SSH key from your Windows home into your WSL home and it should work properly.

Comment: how do I get to it? sorry, I've never used this before, so I don't really know how it works :<

Comment: Open your WSL shell, and you will by default be in your home directory.  Run the command `cp -pr /mnt/c/Users/yourusername/.ssh ./.ssh`.

Comment: that copies the whole ssh folder from windows to wsl ssh folder? It's still saying it can't find the id_rsa file

Comment: `cp -pr` is unlikely to work here because it will create everything 777 and ssh won't like it. You'll need to fix up the permissions afterwards.